# Difference between webdriverJS ,webdriverIO and nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, webdriverjs

I am trying to choose a tool to work with for JAVASCRIPT automation tests. Until now i used Selenium Webdriver JAVA language with testng to build my tests, but for a specific reason i have been asked to search for JAVASCRIPT solution to write tests. I had seen three frameworks similar that is webdriverjs,webdriverio and nightwatchjs. Please help me to understand the difference so i can choose the right framework for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find most of the answer [here](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/138#issuecomment-32051980). Also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqeCUyoIEo8) talk should give you some good insights even though it is a bit outdated since WebdriverIO now fully supports page objects. If you have questions to WebdriverIO checkout our Gitter channel.

Comment: i had gone through those links and i am not clear about one thing.After I had gone through it I found webdriver Js is better when compared with webdriverIO and nightwatchjs.My doubt is webdriverJs with mocha making webdriverJs async nature to sync with the help of default promise library of mocha.Can we make  webdriverJs as sync with  cucumber too?If so any help on this is highly regarded.

Comment: Why is it better? You can run sync commands with WebdriverIO and Cucumber very easily see https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/wdio/runner-specs/cucumber/step-definitions.js

Comment: But webDriverIO is using chain based implementation.So will end up with pyramid of doom and some times will get chain breaking problems if we want to write complex code like array of web elements etc...and we have to use promises for each and every line